# How can I get namespace prefix by namespace URL in XML file?

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to get namespace prefix by namespace URL with xslt transformation. For example, if I have something

```
`xmlns:com="http://system-services.test/ServiceManagement/OIS_Services_v01.00/common"`
```

I pass `http://system-services.test/ServiceManagement/OIS_Services_v01.00/common` and I get `com` in my xsl file.

Edit. Just for example: I have this xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:wor="http://test/ServAndResMgmt/TechOrderMgmt/WorkorderProvider_v01.00" xmlns:typ="http://test/ServAndResMgmt/TechOrderMgmt/WorkorderProvider_v01.00/types"
    xmlns:csdg="http://schemas.telekom.net/csdg_v01.01" xmlns:typ1="http://test/ServiceManagement/TechnicalOrderManagement/Workorder_v01.00/types"
    xmlns:com="http://test/ServiceManagement/OIS_Services_v01.00/common">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:variable name="var">
        <xsl:text>com</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <CreateWorkorder>

            <xsl:element name="{$var}:rr">
                <xsl:value-of select="//*:ticketTaskID/*:value"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </CreateWorkorder>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now, does any function that allows me save namespace prefix in variable "var"?

Answer (score 1):

Use the XPath expression:

```
namespace::*[. = 'http://.../OIS_Services_v01.00/common']/name()
```

with the context node being an element where this namespace is in scope.

Comment: ... which may, of course, give you more than one result if there are several different prefixes all mapped to the same URI.

Comment: can you explain more this answer?) My task is to create element with prefix namespace, but I don't understand how to use your answer)

Comment: If I've misunderstood your question, then sorry, but I think your addition to the question only makes me more confused. It's always better to describe the input and desired output of your transformation.